# Is it possible to reduce this? (or destructuring assignment in Java)

Tags: java

I have a `getSource` method that return a `Pair<String,String>` and I want to call the method and associate the key and the value to two different variables.

I do it like this:

```
entryMode = getSource(encounterAdmitSource).getKey();
admitSource = getSource(encounterAdmitSource).getValue();
```

My question is: is there a way in java to do something like that:

```
getSource(encounterAdmitSource){ //Something 
    entryMode = getKey();
    admitSource=getValue();
}
```

I want to initialize entryMode and admitSource by call only once the method and without create a `Pair<String,String>` object.
Does it exist?
Thank you.

Comment: no. but you can create an object that build that for you

Comment: seems like [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and it's not available in Java

Comment: Arf :/  It's sad

Comment: Java has progressed with version8 / streams but still there's a lot missing vs scala or kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using Optional, this is the best you could do (safely) for the given example

```
final Pair<String, String> source = getSource(encounterAdmitSource);
if (source!=null) { 
    String entryMode = source.getKey();
    String admitSource=source.getValue();
}
```